# How to get Windows 10 Shortcut Key to work

Tags: windows, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to set a Shortcut key to open a Chrome on my Windows 10 Pro laptop.
But nothing happens when I press shortcut.

Here's what I did:

1. right-click Chrome icon
2. select Properties
3. set Shortcut Key to something not already assigned (ie. ctrl + shift + alt + C)
4. OK

nothing happens when I press ctrl + shift + alt + C.

Comment: Works for me. What is your keyboard layout, English?

Comment: @harrymc Probably, based on their profile.

Comment: harrymc:  Yes, English.  Has never worked for me on any Windows computer for at least the last 15 years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had this same problem. The only way to get the hotkey to work is if the program's shortcut is placed on the Desktop (and the hotkey set there).

You also may be able to place the shortcut in Programs :

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
```

Then log out and log back in.

The most surefire way to bypass these issues is to use a program like [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm) and create shortcuts using the [Run](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm) command.

Comment: Works!  THANK YOU! How'd you figure this out??  I've had problem since 1980's. Unbelievable Microsoft never fixed this bug for 30+ years.  Vive superuser.com !!

Comment: No problem! It was sometime back but like many Windows issues, I recall it plagued me for awhile until I figured out the frustratingly arbitrary solution

Comment: This actually works like this since ever, it has to be on desktop or start menu.